# Start a Chat without Waiting for the Notification

Tags: support

I was checking around to start a chat with users within the context of some questions but I couldn't find anywhere. Therefore I am asking: Can we start the chat on Stack Overflow without having to wait for that notification when multiple frequent comments occur within a question/response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have over 100 reputation, meaning you have the privilege to [create chat rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms).